What are these on my cabbages?
These weird little things contribute to appear on my cabbages since it was little, does anybody know what they are or how I could prevent them?


You have a nice colony of cabbage aphids. These aphids have a penchant for brassicas, and like all aphids tend to multiply quickly.
Prevention is difficult, the typical methods fall in three categories:

Manual removal (wash or wipe them off)
Beneficial insects
Chemical treatments like sprays

Healthy plants will be a) less attractive (don’t ask me why) and b) able to tolerate a limited amount of damage. So apart from treatment, making sure your cabbage is as healthy as possible and has good nutrition is an important additional step.

Looks like cabbage aphid to me too!
